# differences in C: *source++, (*source)++, *(source)++

Tags: c, pointers

IS there a difference between these pointers? What exactly is happening here for each call.

1. *p++
2. (*p)++,
3. *(p)++

Comment: '()' have the highest priority, then '++' and then '*' https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: It was a question asked in class not an exam question. I am sitting around after class with no way of testing it and googling on my phone isn't revealing anything. I was curious.

Comment: You may find [this reference](http://www.isthe.com/chongo/tech/comp/c/c-precedence.html) useful. It explains the precedence of each operator, so you can figure out which operators bind to each value and in what order. (basically order-of-operations, although not exactly the same.) You may also want to look up "post-increment" and "pre-increment". That'll explain the difference between `p++` and `++p`, which is the most significant case in which precedence and order-of-operations don't mean the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

1 and 3 are the same.

Remember that both postfix and unary forms of `++` and `--` have a *result* and a *side effect*:

- The result of `x++` is the current value of `x` - as a side effect, `x` is incremented by 1 (if `x` is a pointer, it is incremented to point to the next object in a sequence);
- The result of `++x` is the current value of `x` *plus 1* - as a side effect, `x` is incremented by 1 (if `x` is a pointer, the result is the address of the next object in a sequence, and `x` is updated to point to the next object in a sequence);

Both forms of `--` work the same way, except the value is decremented by 1 - if it's a pointer, then it's set to point to the previous object in a sequence.

When you throw pointer dereferences into the mix, you get the following:

- The expression `*p++` is parsed as `*(p++)` (so is `*(p)++`).  The result of `*p++` is the current value of `*p` (the value of the thing `p` is currently pointing to). As a side effect, `p` is incremented to point to the next object of the same type in a sequence (IOW, the next element of an array);
- The expression `(*p)++` is parsed as written.  The result of `(*p)++` is the current value of `*p`. As a side effect, `*p` is incremented by 1.  That is, the value of the thing being pointed to is updated, not the pointer.
- The expression `++*p` is parsed as `++(*p)`.  The result of `++*p` is the current value of `*p` plus 1.  As a side effect, `*p` is incremented by 1.
- The expression `*++p` is parsed as `*(++p)`.  The result of `*++p` is the value of the object *following* the object `p` currently points to.  As a side effect, `p` is incremented to point to the next object.

Assume the following declarations:

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
int *p = a;
```

After these lines, the value of `p` is `&a[0]`.  So, given the expression

```
x = *p++;
```

the *result* of `*p++` is `1` (the value of the thing `p` currently points to), which gets assigned to `x`.  The *side effect* is that `p` is updated to point to `a[1]`.

Then we execute

```
x = (*p)++;
```

The *result* of `(*p)++` is the value of the thing `p` currently points to (if `p` points to `a[1]`, then the value is `2`), which gets assigned to `x`.  As a side effect, the thing `p` points to is incremented (if `p` points to `a[1]`, then the value of `a[1]` is now `3`).

The we execute

```
x = ++*p;
```

The result of `++*p` is the value of the thing `p` points to plus 1, and as a result the thing `p` points to is incremented (if `p` points to `a[1]`, then the value of `a[1] + 1` is `4`, which is assigned to `x`, and the value of `a[1]` is now `4`).

Finally, we execute

```
x = *++p;
```

The result of `*++p` is the value of the object *following* the object that `p` currently points to, and `p` is incremented to point to that object (if `p` points to `a[1]`, then the value of `a[2]` (`3`) is written to `x`, and `p` is updated to point to `a[2]`).

Again, `--` works the same way, just in the other direction.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "side-effect"?

Comment: @trev: A side effect is anything that modifies the state of the execution environment - changing the value of an object, modifying a file, calling a function, etc.  In this case, we’re changing the value of an object through the `++` and `––` operators.

Comment: Actually i have one doubt, in this expression *p++, the precedence of *(indifference operator) and ++(increment operator) is same, so how did we evaluate that which operator will be applied first on p?

Comment: @trev: *Postfix* `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`, so it is parsed as `*(p++)` - we are dereferencing the result of `p++`.  *Unary* `++` has the same precedence as unary `*`, so it's evaluated left-to-right - `*++p` is evaluated as `*(++p)` (dereferencing the result of `++p`) and `++*p` is evaluated as `++(*p)` (incrementing the result of `*p`).

Answer (score 1):

tiny test program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char z[] = "World";
    char n[] = "Something";
    char *x = "Hello!!";


    while(*x) printf("%c", *x++);
    printf("\n");
    x = z;
    while(*x) printf("%c", (*x)++);
    printf("\n");
    x = n;
    while(*x) printf("%c", *(x)++);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

so the `*x++` dereference the pointer, then increments the pointer
`(*x)++` - only increments the referenced object.
`*(x)++` == `*x++`

IMO instead of asking try yourself. You will learn something https://ideone.com/bliza0

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`*source++` will be parsed as `*(source++)` because of higher [precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) of `++` over `*` operator. It will increment the pointer by 1 and then will dereference the pointer.</strike>

---

To understand the behaviour first let me explain how post increment operator works. When you do

```
int i = 0;
int j = i++;
```

then it means that the value of the expression `i++` will be the value of the operand `i`. In this case it will be `0`. The value of the `i` will be incremented as a side-effect. See the quote from the draft

n1570 - §6.5.2.4/2:

> **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand**. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it). See the discussions of additive operators and compound assignment for information on constraints, types, and conversions and the effects of operations on pointers. **The value computation of the result is sequenced before the side effect of updating the stored value of the operand**.

In case of `*source++`, compiler will parse it as `*(source++)`. The result of the expression `source++` is the value of `source`. So the current pointer (the address `source` is pointing to before the side-effect) will be dereferenced and then the side-effect on `source` will be performed.

`(*source)++` will first dereference the pointer and then increment the dereferenced value by 1.

`*(source)++` is equivalent to the first case.

---

<sub>I apologies for the wrong answer and leaving the wrong answer with strikes so that future readers will take a lesson if any one come to the same wrong conclusion as I did. Thanks @interjay and @pmg for correcting me out. I am really glad that you guys are part of this community and contributing to this community with your sharp eyes and mind.</sub>

Comment: `*source++` will increment the pointer *after* dereferencing it. Your answer makes it sound like it will dereference the incremented pointer.

Comment: @interjay `++` has higer precedence over `*`.

Comment: @haccks This is post-increment which gives the original value of the pointer. This is what is dereferenced. The pointer is then incremented.

Comment: Operator precedence doesn't determine order of operations, it only determines how the expression is parsed. This is basic C and I'm surprised so many people are getting this wrong. [Here](https://ideone.com/wwBtkV) is a demonstration that clearly shows that the original value of the pointer is dereferenced.

Comment: [`char *source = "foo"; printf("%c\n", *source++) /* f, not o */;`](https://ideone.com/GnVhof)

Comment: Also consider the classic implementation of `strcpy`: `while(*dest++ = *src++);`. This wouldn't work if this answer was correct.

Comment: It is largely academic - the take home here is not to write code like that but rather write code that clearly expresses what you intend without needing to understand the subtle semantics.  I'd not write either expression, but rather `p = *source; source++;` or `source++; p = *source ;` which removes all ambiguity.  I dislike classes that try to teach the semantics of this kind when they'd do better to simply emphasise clear and unambiguous code - it is of course unambiguous to the compiler but you'll get a lot more bug-free code written in life if you simply avoid this nonsense.

Comment: @Clifford Code like this is actually commonly seen, so this is not just academic and it's important to be able to read it (even if you don't use it yourself). The K&R book, for example, uses it in implementations of functions like `strcpy` as I showed above.